# Can't reference Microsoft.Practices namespace after NuGet update

Tags: mvvm-light

I updated NuGet packages today (8/19/2014) for both MVVM Light and the CommonServiceLocator. After doing this, my project can no longer resolve the Microsoft.Practices namespace. This means that the following won't work:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
```

What should I do to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a namespace collision with another package perhaps?

You can access the object with it's full namespace:

Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator

Posting the full error message will help.

Can you make sure that the CommonServiceLocator dll and reference made it into the project?